# mmc.exe - Application Unable to Start (0xc0000102)

Tags: windows-10, mmc

When i'm trying to run anything from the MMC or any MSC related apps in my local account (An Administrator), all i get is an error : The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000102)., and if i do try running mmc.exe, all i get is a Blank MMC, and the taskbar name "Console1". But if i do try running it thru an elevated CMD, i can start them fine (Example: compmgmt.msc). I have tried running SFC, DISM, and chkdsk /f /r, but they all do return a "normal" answer (all is fine).

Steps Reproduced:

1. SFC/ SCANNOW: no integrity violations
2. DISM: all is good
3. chkdsk/f /r - **initially what caused the problems in MMC, and other areas of the laptop. I ran a chkdsk command from my laptop when it suddenly caused a bootloop. (Stuck in Preparing Startup Repair)**
4. regsvr32 msxml.dll/msxml2.dll.msxml3.dll: msxml and msxml2 not found in sys32 folder. only msxml3.

Workarounds:
1. Start .msc's from Elevated CMD

Other related Problems Found:

1. Missing MSXML and MSXML2. (but sfc and dism still does not recognize these problems)

Is there any fix to these problems? Aside from a full reset (a last resort)?

Comment: Do they work correctly for other user accounts? How about from yours, only in Safe Mode?  If you were having disk errors, then a reset is probably your best bet (after ensuring the disk is OK and/or replaced), as  based on what's here, it sounds like it's a permissions problem (possibly ACL corruption caused by disk errors), and those are usually REALLY hard to find (to correct).

Comment: It sounds like the application is not having access to some resource. Could it be that you installed a new .NET Framework? Maybe some files changed ownership

Comment: Or have you uninstalled the .NET Framework?

Comment: as an addition to the launching of administrative tools on an elevated cmd, they will also work in their normal way of launching (Win+X; Searching the tools) IF i turn off UAC

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to run mmc because it was blocked by the administrador (even though I am administrator) and this is how I solve it

1. Restart your computer in safemode: run **msconfig** and enable Safe boot

[image]

2. After windows has restarted in **safemode** run **secpol.msc**
3. Go to `Local Polices/Security Options` look for the option `User Account Control: Run All Administrators in Admin Aproval Mode` and disable that option
   [image]
4. Disable the safeboot using the msconfig and restart your computer